# Fieldset .change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange, fieldset

I'm trying to change a button value on triggering a radio button.

```
<fieldset id="product-color">
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="color" value="Red">
    <label for="red">Red</label><br> 
    <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" value="Blue">
    <label for="blue">Blue</label><br> 
</fieldset>

<button
id="order-button"
data-item-id="1"
data-item-name="Shirt"
data-item-price="20"
data-item-custom2-name="Color"
data-item-custom2-options="Red|Blue">
Add Item
</button>
```

By using this small script:

```
$('#product-color').change(function() {
    $('#order-button').data('item-custom2-value', $(this).val());
});
```

With a select-input-field it works quite fine, but not with a fieldset. Is there any difference?

Comment: OP is a bit unclear which event you want to change the value on button click or radio button change. also which value you want to assign as data value for the fieldset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change event for radio button as event is fired on radio button and not fieldset:

```
$('#product-color input').change(function() {
   $('#order-button').data('item-custom2-value', $(this).val());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htx47xy4/)**